iOS 17. Video, shows a black screen when opening in full screen mode with a poster
Browser: Safari/Chrome
Operating system: Ios 17
 
At startup, full screen mode opens. There is sound, but no video.
<video ref="video"
   :src="videoSrc"
   :poster="poster"
   @play="onPlay">
</video>

onPlay() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    this.$refs.video.webkitEnterFullscreen();
    }, 150); 
},

I tried this option. In some cases it helps. But not in all of them. Does anyone know the solution?

See also https://github.com/cookpete/react-player/issues/1732.

I had the same issue and found that removing the poster attribute fixes the issue. No idea why right now, it's likely an ios17 bug.
So you probably should be able to fix your code with :
<video ref="video" :src="videoSrc" @play="onPlay"></video>
